# Is there a way to import a formatted string into a google spreadsheet with ImportXML or ImportHTML?

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets, youtube

I know this function is usually used for calling in data from a website, but I only need one number. I'm creating a spreadsheet of YouTubers which is supposed to include their subscriber count. Instead of manually updating their subscriber counts all the time, I'd like to have the "subscriber" cell import the number directly from their YouTube page and display it as it updates. I've been fiddling with the commands for a while and can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look and my conclusion is that Socialblade makes it much easier to do the job. You just need to inspect the subscriber count and get the id of the span class. For example:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/ChannelName", "//span[@id='youtube-stats-header-subs']")
```

**References**

- [ImportXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en&ref_topic=9199554)